# nginx url rewrite with string substitution

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to catch if my urls contain a small substr, keep the url as it is and rewrite only that small part, how can I accomplish this?

For example:

```
http://foobar.com/foo-bar-substrtocatch-baz
```

should become

```
http://foobar.com/foo-bar-changedsubstr-baz
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rewrite    ^(.*)substrtocatch(.*)$    $1changedsubstr$2;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `return` be better to inform SEO and robots of the 301?

Comment: @ZacGrierson It depends on what you want to do; if a 301 is required, just use the `permanent` flag as per http://nginx.org/r/rewrite